# Add value to integer in do-while loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, do-while

I'm having trouble having the do-while loop successfully change the integer to the value inside the if statement. It will exit the loop correctly if I enter '**y**' or '**n**', but the value of the integer will stay at 0.

I'm using substrings to allow the user to enter something like "**yes**" or "**YEs**", even "**Y3$ir**" and still equate to a '**y**' to java.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class aTaskforAll
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String readAll;

        int readAllOption = 0;

        do {
            System.out.print("Do you want the words printed? (y/n) ");
            readAll = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(readAll.substring(0));

            if ((readAll.substring(0) == "y") || (readAll.substring(0) == "Y"))
                readAllOption = 1;
            else if ((readAll.substring(0) == "n") || (readAll.substring(0) == "N"))
                readAllOption = 2;
        }
        while (readAllOption != 0);

        System.out.println(readAllOption);    //Tester

        //Go on to do task in response to readAllOption = 1 or 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`String.substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) method does not do what you think it does.

Following is what the documentation says:

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string.

So, `readAll.substring(0)` will give you a substring which will basically have all the characters from the original string.

The correct method for your use case is [`String.substring(int,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).

From the docs

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.

So, `readAll.substring(0, 1)` will give you a substring with only the first character.

Or it would be even better (cleaner) to use [`String.startsWith(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method

```
if (readAll.startsWith("y") || readAll.startsWith("Y"))
    //...
```

---

Another problem is that are using `==` for object (strings in your case) equality check:

```
//...
if ((readAll.substring(0) == "y") || (readAll.substring(0) == "Y"))
//...
else if ((readAll.substring(0) == "n") || (readAll.substring(0) == "N"))
//...
```

Don't use `==`, use `.equals` method instead for equality check. `==` is for identity check, which means just comparing the references.

---

Also, you should reset the value of `readAllOption` at the beginning of each iteration:

```
do {
    readAllOption = 0;
```

to exit the loop.

Comment: -1 readAll.substring(0) does nothing.  It returns the entire String.

Comment: I like using .startsWith for this situation. Thank you!

Comment: @BheshGurung Your original answer was in error (substring args). Rather than adding a correction as an edit, fix the original problem.

Comment: I mean you should edit your answer to make it look as if you had all the right information from the start.  The objective is to make the answer as useful as possible to others who come searching later, as well as for the OP.  Don't make others have to mentally keep track of the changes as they read.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Agreed. I have edited it. I hope it looks better this time. Let me know if I am stilling missing something.

Comment: @user949300: Thanks for the suggestion and also for -(-1) :).

Answer (score 1):

First, your termination condition is backwards.

You want

```
do {
  stuff...
}
while (readAllOption  == 0)
```

As written, it will only exit the loop when readAllOption  == 0.
And you need to set it to 0 at the start of each loop.

Secondly, `readAll.subString(0)` returns the entire String.  You want `readAll.charAt(0)`, and compare that to the chars 'Y' or 'N'.

I have NO idea how this code was even remotely working for you.

Answer (score 1):

With strings you need to use `.equals("y")` not `==` and you didn't have an ending index for the substring.
so like this

```
if (readAll.substring(0, 1).equals("y")){}
```

As Bhesh Gurung said

> Also, you should reset the value of readAllOption at the beginning of each iteration:
>
> do {
>      readAllOption = 0;

also as user user949300 said

> Your termination condition is backwards.
>
> You want
>
> do {
>    stuff...
>      }
>      while (readAllOption  == 0)
>   As written, it will only exit the loop when readAllOption == 0

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung just beat me to it

Comment: Haha, thank you though! I did use your idea for ending the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.equals()` instead of `==` when comparing strings.

Just getting the first character would also work (and it will be more efficient):

`readAll.charAt(0) == 'y'`

Comment: +1 for for charAt().  -1 for saying that it is more efficient.  The issue is that readAllOption.subString(0) is outright wrong...

Comment: @user949300: Thanks for your input. How is it not more efficient? `subString()` creates a new string object whereas `charAt()` is a constant time operation returning a char.

Comment: Unless he is calling this in a loop 100000 times a second, it won't matter.  (But, basically you missed the bug in the concern for efficiency)

Comment: (Though I may have mixed up your post with another...)

Comment: @user949300: I thought it was obvious from the use of parenthesis that it was more of a "hey just so you know this is more efficient" type thing. To your point, using `charAt()` in this instance doesn't offer a performance benefit. However I think this information can become useful to the OP down the road when his assignments get more complex. Stopping a complex algorithm to allocate memory instead of a constant time method call? Just thought it may become useful.

Comment: I didn't have much of a for that form of accuracy. Negligible in this situation @user949300. 

But thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Make your code like this. Maintaining integrity of it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class aTaskforAll
  {
  public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String readAll;

    int readAllOption = 0;

    do {
        System.out.print("Do you want the words printed? (y/n) ");
        readAll = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(readAll.substring(0));

        if ("y".equals(readAll.substring(0,1).toLowerCase())
            readAllOption = 1;
        else if ("n".equals(readAll.substring(0,1).toLowerCase())
            readAllOption = 2;
        }
    while (readAllOption != 0);

    System.out.println(readAllOption);    //Tester

    //Go on to do task in response to readAllOption = 1 or 2
   }
}
```